# AngularFire: $add sets fbUID and custom UID, why?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

Before there are any questions, I have a function that creates a custom UID because I don't "need" the long Firebase UID and wanted something shorter which is more easy to remember.

Anyway, in my create-function I'm not sure I'm adding it to the db correctly.
Here's a snippet and below that is how it looks in my database.

```
$scope.create = function(){
          // Generate a shorter random uid (6 chars) that replaces the long regular Firebase uid
          letters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
          uid_length = 6;
          generator = function(){
            random = '';
            for(var i = 0; i < uid_length; i++){
              random += letters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length));
            }
            return random;
          }
          generator();

          var lists = new Firebase('https://url.firebaseio.com/lists/' + random);
          firebaseLists = $firebaseArray(lists);

          //lists.child(random).set(random);
          firebaseLists.$add(random).then(function(lists){
          })
```

This gives me, for example:

```
lists
   0Knn8M <- custom UID
     -KH6kSxPAaerjU: '0Knn8M'
```

As I want the things that are added to 0Knn8M displayed on my page, it also displays the FB UID. Of course I could do a CSS 'display:none;' on that child but shouldn't it be another way around it?

Comment: Whe you use $add on a firebasearray it will generate a unique firebase id for you. To prevent that you should use a different method of saving to firebase.

Comment: @AndréKool oh that's true. I removed the whole $add-function and just did "firebaseLists.$set(random), didn't work at first but when I placed it inside the generator-function it seems to do what I want. Now I just need to sort out the list view which behaves badly because of this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think, that here is an error:

```
generator = function(){
  random = '';
  for(var i = 0; i < uid_length; i++){
    random += letters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length));
  }
  return random;
}
generator();

var lists = new Firebase('https://url.firebaseio.com/lists/' + random);
```

You are calling `generator()` but not assigning it result to any variable. In `var lists = new Firebase('https://url.firebaseio.com/lists/' + random);` the variable `random` is now `undefined`. So firebase generates it's own id I guess.
So you need to change just one thing `var random = generator()`.